# What is the "DC OK" relay used for on a power supply?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I am using a [Meanwell SDR-120-12](http://www.meanwell.com/search/sdr-120/default.htm) power supply for a project. I noticed it has terminals for "DC OK" which the datasheet refers to as a relay contact rated for

> 60Vdc/0.3A, 30Vdc/1A, 30Vac/0.5A resistive load

It also says:

> Contact Close = PSU turns on / DC OK.
>
> Contact Open = PSU turns off / DC Fail.
>
> Contact Ratings (max.) = 30V / 1A resistive load

The block diagram seems to show that this is a relay that's operated by the power supply being energized. I assume this contact might stay open if the power supply did not pass some sort of self test at power-up? If that's true, then is the "DC OK" terminal meant as a means for equipment to detect if power is fully available (sort of like how a computer PSU communicates to a motherboard)?

How is this different from simply using output power from the supply to operate a device and not utilizing the relay at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe on most supplies it's just an indication that the power supply is regulated within preset limits. While it could be useful in the case of fault conditions I think the main purpose is during the power up and power down ramp if you don't want the circuit to be exposed to those ramps or to only wish to take measurements when the supply is at full voltage. I see the supply you've mentioned is a DIN rail supply so that's the most likely reason in this case and/or for connection to external alarms and monitoring systems.

On a bench supply one example I can think of is that if you were using a power supply with remote control capabilities you may want to perform automated repeated testing of what happens when power is abruptly removed. In that case you could use the DC OK relay to quickly remove power instead of the power slowly ramping down as the output filtering caps discharge.

Comment: Yes, several of these mount to a DIN rail on the back of the unit to facilitate easy removal/addition. We aren't using the "DC OK" as yet, but it might be good to incorporate it. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

Some circuits may behave in undesired fashion if they are driven with less than full power.  Additionally, some devices have multiple power-supply inputs, and may be damaged if a "high power" supply is enabled while the control circuitry (which is driven by a lower voltage supply) is not active.  If a power supply is used to operate the control-voltage side of things, a "DC OK" output may be used to disconnect the high-power supply except when the proper control voltage is being supplied.

Answer (score 0):

It is used as visual indicator that your PSU is running correctly or not and in industrial setting is used to let a PLC know that there is an issue or not.

Comment: The contacts don't give a visual indication but otherwise correct. Welcome to EE.SE.